# iPhone & iPad - how to include frameworks in a project with two targets

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

I have a project that was developed for iPhone OS 2.0. I am transforming this project to have two targets (iPhone & iPad). This will not be a universal binary. It will have two different binaries.

In the old project, if I right click on a framework and choose REVEAL IN FINDER, I see the framework is a 2.0 one, for example, UIKit is linked to the path

**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk/...**

the same framework for 3.2 is on

**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/...**

So, they are different files, in different paths.

How should I proceed? I suppose this is a problem. I think I must link each target to a different version of the framework, but how do I do that?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk/` file is just the sysroot. The actually linked file is still `/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit`.

The SDK version also specify the minimum requirement the device must run on. As long as you're only using the public SDK there should be no problem recompiling for 3.2 with no change (except lots of "deprecated" messages). But compiling for 3.2 means devices having < 3.2 cannot use your app.

If there's no big change I suggest keep the iPhone version as-is. Then clone the project for iPad and consider how to fit your UI elements into 1024x768, is it necessary to take advantage of the new capabilities, etc.